# Cumulative sum in a window (or running window sum) based on a condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am trying to calculate cumulative sum for a given window based on a condition. I have seen threads where the solution does conditional cumulative sum ([Calculate a conditional running sum in R for every row in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097646/calculate-a-conditional-running-sum-in-r-for-every-row-in-data-frame)) and rolling sum ([Rolling Sum by Another Variable in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397299/rolling-sum-by-another-variable-in-r/24400600#24400600)), but I couldn't find the two together. I also saw that `data.table` doesn't have a rolling window function at [R data.table sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676476/r-data-table-sliding-window). So, this problem is very challenging for me.

Moreover, the [solution posted by Mike Grahan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24400600/5713272) on rolling sum is beyond my comprehension. I am looking for `data.table` based method primarily for speed. However, I am open to other methods if they are understandable.

Here's my input data:

```
DFI <- structure(list(FY = c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2016, 2011, 2011, 
2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2010, 2016, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2010), 
    Customer = c(13575, 13575, 13575, 13575, 13575, 13575, 13575, 
    13575, 13575, 13575, 13575, 13578, 13578, 13578, 13578, 13578, 
    13578), Product = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), Rev = c(4, 
    3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2)), .Names = c("FY", 
"Customer", "Product", "Rev"), row.names = c(NA, 17L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's my expected output: (Manually created; My apologies if there is a manual error)

```
DFO <- structure(list(FY = c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2016, 2011, 2012, 
2013, 2014, 2015, 2010, 2016, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2010), Customer = c(13575, 
13575, 13575, 13575, 13575, 13575, 13575, 13575, 13575, 13575, 
13578, 13578, 13578, 13578, 13578, 13578), Product = c("A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", 
"E"), Rev = c(4, 3, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2), 
    cumsum = c(4, 7, 10, 11, 9, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 3, 2, 2, 4, 
    2, 2)), .Names = c("FY", "Customer", "Product", "Rev", "cumsum"
), row.names = c(NA, 16L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Some commentary about the logic:**

1) I want to find rolling sum in a 5-year period. Ideally, I would like this 5-year period to be variable i.e. something I can specify elsewhere in the code. This way, I have the liberty to vary the window later on for my analysis.

2) The end of Window is based on the maximum year (i.e. `FY` in example above). In above example, the max `FY` in `DFI` is `2016`. So, starting year of the window would be `2016 - 5 + 1 = 2012` for all entries in `2016`.

3) The window sum (or running sum) is calculated by `Customer` and for a specific `Product`.

**What I tried:**

I wanted to try something before posting. Here's my code:

```
  DFI <- data.table::as.data.table(DFI)

  #Sort it first
  DFI<-DFI[order(Customer,FY),]

  #find cumulative sum; remove Rev column; order rows
  DFOTest<-DFI[,cumsum := cumsum(Rev),by=.(Customer,Product)][,.SD[which.max(cumsum)],by=.(FY,Customer,Product)][,("Rev"):=NULL][order(Customer,Product,FY)]
```

This code calculates the cumulative sum, but I am unable to define 5-year window and then calculate running sum. I have two questions:

**Question 1)** How do I calculate a 5-year running sum?

**Question 2)** Can someone please explain [Mike's method on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24400600/5713272) ? It seems to be fast. However, I am not really sure what's going on there. I did see that someone requested some commentary, but I am not sure whether it is self-explanatory.

Thanks in advance. I have been struggling on this problem for two days.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1) rollapply** Create a `Sum` function which takes `FY` and `Rev` as a 2 column matrix (or if not makes it one) and then sums the revenues for those years within `k` of the last year.  Then convert `DFI` to a data table, sum rows having the same Customer/Product/Year and run `rollapplyr` with `Sum` for each Customer/Product group.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

k <- 5
Sum <- function(x) {
  x <- matrix(x,, 2)
  FY <- x[, 1]
  Rev <- x[, 2]
  ok <- FY >= tail(FY, 1) - k + 1
  sum(Rev[ok])
}
DT <- as.data.table(DFI)
DT <- DT[, list(Rev = sum(Rev)), by = c("Customer", "Product", "FY")]
DT[, cumsum := rollapplyr(.SD, k, Sum, by.column = FALSE, partial = TRUE),
       by = c("Customer", "Product"), .SDcols = c("FY", "Rev")]
```

giving:

```
 > DT
    Customer Product   FY Rev cumsum
 1:    13575       A 2011   4      4
 2:    13575       A 2012   3      7
 3:    13575       A 2013   3     10
 4:    13575       A 2015   1     11
 5:    13575       A 2016   2      9
 6:    13575       B 2011   3      3
 7:    13575       B 2012   3      6
 8:    13575       B 2013   4     10
 9:    13575       B 2014   5     15
10:    13575       B 2015   6     21
11:    13578       A 2010   3      3
12:    13578       A 2016   2      2
13:    13578       B 2013   2      2
14:    13578       C 2014   4      4
15:    13578       D 2015   2      2
16:    13578       E 2010   2      2
```

**2) data.table only**

First sum rows that have the same Customer/Product/FY and then, grouping by Customer/Product, for each FY value, `fy`, pick out the `Rev` values whose FY values are between `fy-k+1` and `fy` and sum.

```
library(data.table)

k <- 5
DT <- as.data.table(DFI)
DT <- DT[, list(Rev = sum(Rev)), by = c("Customer", "Product", "FY")]
DT[, cumsum := sapply(FY, function(fy) sum(Rev[between(FY, fy-k+1, fy)])),
       by = c("Customer", "Product")]
```

giving:

```
> DT
    Customer Product   FY Rev cumsum
 1:    13575       A 2011   4      4
 2:    13575       A 2012   3      7
 3:    13575       A 2013   3     10
 4:    13575       A 2015   1     11
 5:    13575       A 2016   2      9
 6:    13575       B 2011   3      3
 7:    13575       B 2012   3      6
 8:    13575       B 2013   4     10
 9:    13575       B 2014   5     15
10:    13575       B 2015   6     21
11:    13578       A 2010   3      3
12:    13578       A 2016   2      2
13:    13578       B 2013   2      2
14:    13578       C 2014   4      4
15:    13578       D 2015   2      2
16:    13578       E 2010   2      2
```

Comment: The data.table solution is beautiful!

Answer (score 4):

My solution stays on the `tidyverse` side of things, however, if your source data is not excessive the performance difference may not be an issue.

I will start with declaring a function to calculate the rolling sum using `tibbletime::rollify` and expand the data frame to include missing `FY` values. Then group and summarise while applying the rolling sum.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

rollsum_5 <- tibbletime::rollify(sum, window = 5)

df %>%
  complete(FY, Customer, Product) %>%
  replace_na(list(Rev = 0), Rev) %>%
  arrange(Customer, Product, FY) %>%
  group_by(Customer, Product, FY) %>%
  summarise(Rev = sum(Rev)) %>%
  mutate(cumsum = rollsum_5(Rev)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  filter(Rev != 0)

# # A tibble: 16 x 5
#    Customer Product    FY   Rev cumsum
#       <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#  1    13575 A        2011  4.00  NA   
#  2    13575 A        2012  3.00  NA   
#  3    13575 A        2013  3.00  NA   
#  4    13575 A        2015  1.00  11.0 
#  5    13575 A        2016  2.00   9.00
#  6    13575 B        2011  3.00  NA   
#  7    13575 B        2012  3.00  NA   
#  8    13575 B        2013  4.00  NA   
#  9    13575 B        2014  5.00  15.0 
# 10    13575 B        2015  6.00  21.0 
# 11    13578 A        2010  3.00  NA   
# 12    13578 A        2016  2.00   2.00
# 13    13578 B        2013  2.00  NA   
# 14    13578 C        2014  4.00   4.00
# 15    13578 D        2015  2.00   2.00
# 16    13578 E        2010  2.00  NA
```

> **N.B.** The rolling sum in this case will only appear in the rows where the window (*5 rows*) are intact. It could be misleading to suggest that partial values are equal to a five year sum.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr), [tidyr](/questions/tagged/tidyr), and [zoo](/questions/tagged/zoo).

```
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(zoo)

# A helper function to convert the rolling cumsum result
cumsum_roll <- function(x){
  vec <- c(x[1, ], x[, ncol(x)][-1])
  return(vec)
}

DFI2 <- DFI %>%
  # Group by FY, Customer, Product
  group_by_at(vars(-Rev)) %>%                 
  # Calculate the total Rev pf each group
  summarise(Rev = sum(Rev)) %>%               
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  # Expand the data frame based on FY and Product
  # Fill the Rev to be 0
  complete(FY = full_seq(FY, period = 1), Product, fill = list(Rev = 0)) %>%
  # Sort the data frame by Customer, FY, and Product
  arrange(Customer, Product, FY) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Customer, Product) %>%
  # Apply the rolling cumsum by rollapply. Specify the window as 5.
  # cumsum_roll is to transcribe the output of rollapply, a matrix, to a vector
  mutate(cumsum = cumsum_roll(rollapply(Rev, 5, FUN = cumsum))) %>%
  # Remove Rev = 0
  filter(Rev != 0) %>%
  # Reorder the columns
  select(FY, Customer, Product, Rev, cumsum) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  as.data.frame()

DFI2
#      FY Customer Product Rev cumsum
# 1  2011    13575       A   4      4
# 2  2012    13575       A   3      7
# 3  2013    13575       A   3     10
# 4  2015    13575       A   1     11
# 5  2016    13575       A   2      9
# 6  2011    13575       B   3      3
# 7  2012    13575       B   3      6
# 8  2013    13575       B   4     10
# 9  2014    13575       B   5     15
# 10 2015    13575       B   6     21
# 11 2010    13578       A   3      3
# 12 2016    13578       A   2      2
# 13 2013    13578       B   2      2
# 14 2014    13578       C   4      4
# 15 2015    13578       D   2      2
# 16 2010    13578       E   2      2
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a new `tidyverse` answer but I think `nest` helps with readability

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

roll_cumsum <- function(df) {
                  df %>%
                     complete(FY = full_seq(FY, period=1)) %>%
                     mutate(roll_cumsum = rollapplyr(Rev, 5, sum, na.rm=TRUE, partial=TRUE))
               }

DFI %>%
  group_by_at(vars(-Rev)) %>%
  summarise(Rev = sum(Rev)) %>%
  group_by(Customer, Product) %>%
  nest(FY, Rev) %>%
  mutate(data = map(data, ~roll_cumsum(.x))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  filter(!is.na(Rev)) %>%
  arrange(Customer, Product, FY)

# A tibble: 16 x 5
   # Customer Product    FY   Rev roll_cumsum
      # <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
 # 1    13575 A        2011  4.00        4.00
 # 2    13575 A        2012  3.00        7.00
 # 3    13575 A        2013  3.00       10.0 
 # 4    13575 A        2015  1.00       11.0 
 # 5    13575 A        2016  2.00        9.00
 # 6    13575 B        2011  3.00        3.00
 # 7    13575 B        2012  3.00        6.00
 # 8    13575 B        2013  4.00       10.0 
 # 9    13575 B        2014  5.00       15.0 
# 10    13575 B        2015  6.00       21.0 
# 11    13578 A        2010  3.00        3.00
# 12    13578 A        2016  2.00        2.00
# 13    13578 B        2013  2.00        2.00
# 14    13578 C        2014  4.00        4.00
# 15    13578 D        2015  2.00        2.00
# 16    13578 E        2010  2.00        2.00
```