# Cumulative sum (or running-window sum) and carry-forward values in a window based on a condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

My question is inspired by [Cumulative sum in a window (or running window sum) based on a condition in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48434157/cumulative-sum-in-a-window-or-running-window-sum-based-on-a-condition-in-r).

I want to calculate running window sum just as in above post with a little twist. I'd want to "carry forward" the value of cumulative sum until "k" years even if there wouldn't be a row that satisfies filter criterion. In other words, we will need to add rows to the original data set.

This problem is challenging because I am still not comfortable with using `apply` function within `data.table`.

Here's my input data:

```
DFI <- structure(list(Year = c(2011, 2013, 2014, 2010, 2012, 2015), 
    Customer = c(13575, 13575, 13575, 13575, 13576, 13576), Product = c("R", 
    "R", "R", "W", "S", "R"), Rev = c(4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Customer", "Product", "Rev"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's my expected output:

```
DFO <- structure(list(Year = c(2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2010, 2011, 
2015, 2012, 2013), Customer = c(13575, 13575, 13575, 13575, 13575, 
13575, 13575, 13576, 13576, 13576), Product = c("R", "R", "R", 
"R", "R", "W", "W", "R", "S", "S"), Rev = c(4, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 
0, 2, 2, 0), CumRev = c(4, 4, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Customer", "Product", "Rev", "CumRev"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Some commentary about how I manually generated `DFO`:

a) Number of years in the window = 2 i.e. `k=2`

b) Although the entry for `Year = 2012`, `Customer = 13575` and `Product = R` doesn't exist in `DFI`  (input data), it was added because the cumulative sum from `Year = 2011` would be carried forward for one more year (i.e. `k-1 = 2-1 = 1`). Hence, for this row, `Rev = 0` and `CumRev = 4`

c) `The entry for Year = 2015`, `Customer = 13575` and `Product = R` was added because there exists at least one entry in the table for `Year = 2015`. In other words, the range of `Year` to be added (or to be carried forward) would depend on two things: 1) The range of `Year` in input table 2) Length of running window.

Now, I did try to solve this problem myself before posting. I have spent close to 36 hours, and I was able to solve this. However, the issue is with `expand.grid.` In actual data, I run out of memory. Hence, I am wondering whether there is any better method (computationally less expensive and memory efficient) to solve this.

Here's my code:

```
Year<-unique(DFI$Year)
  Customer<-unique(DFI$Customer)
  Product<-unique(DFI$Product)
  DFO1<-expand.grid(Year = Year,Customer = Customer,Product = Product) #generate all combinations
  DFO1<-data.table::as.data.table(DFO1)

  #Do join between DFO and DFI to add Rev
  DFO1<-DFI[DFO1,on=c("Product","Customer","Year")]

   k<-2 #Number of years  = 2
   DFO1<-DFO1[order(Customer,Product,Year)]
   DFO1[is.na(Rev)]$Rev<-0

   DFO1<-DFO1[, CumRev := sapply(Year, function(year) sum(Rev[between(Year, year-k+1, year)])), by = .(Customer, Product)][order(Customer,Product,Year)]
   DFO1<-DFO1[CumRev!=0] #Remove zero rows

   DFO<-data.table::as.data.table(DFO)
   DFO<-DFO[order(Customer,Product,Year)]
   compare(DFO1,DFO) #TRUE
```

As someone who is just starting to learn to apply `apply()` in `data.table`, this was tough for me. I'd appreciate any thoughts to optimize this. I am willing to learn from this process. Thank you for your time and for any help extended to me.

Comment: In the `DFO`, the full combinations are not there?

Comment: @akrun - Yes. I removed them (using  `DFO1<-DFO1[CumRev!=0])` because we would only need to carry forward the cumulative sum for `k-1` years.

Comment: why is there no entry for Year=2016, Customer=13576, Product=R?

Comment: @Chinsoon: Thanks for asking. There are two criteria to determine which rows will be added `max(year)` and `k-1`. Please see point c) above. If we had any one entry for, say, any other customer for year `2016`, we would have required to have it. Because there is no entry for `year = 2016`, we get a pass. In simple words, what it means is that `current year = 2015`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation inline. Uses @G.Grothendieck's Sum function and also his application of his `zoo::rollapplyr` from [Cumulative sum in a window (or running window sum) based on a condition in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48434157/cumulative-sum-in-a-window-or-running-window-sum-based-on-a-condition-in-r)

```
k <- 2
Sum <- function(x) {
    x <- matrix(x,, 2)
    FY <- x[, 1]
    Rev <- x[, 2]
    ok <- FY >= tail(FY, 1) - k + 1
    sum(Rev[ok])
}    


setDT(DFI)
#This is prob the only difference from your solution
#create a combination of year to year + k for each Customer and product.
#Then subset to remove future years
combis <- unique(rbindlist(lapply(seq_len(k), 
    function(n) unique(DFI[, .(Year=Year+n-1, Customer, Product)]))))[
        Year <= DFI[,max(Year)]]

#lookup revenue
out <- DFI[combis, on=.(Year, Customer, Product)][,
    Rev := ifelse(is.na(Rev), 0, Rev)]

#order before summing
setorder(out, Customer,Product,Year)
out[,CumRev := zoo::rollapplyr(.SD, k, Sum, by.column = FALSE, partial = TRUE),
    by = c("Customer", "Product"), .SDcols = c("Year", "Rev")][]
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Could you please explain `unique(DFI[, .(Year=Year+n-1, Customer, Product)]))))`?

Comment: It just takes your data set of product and customer and add a few years. For example if your window is 2 with a customer A, product P and year Y, it adds customer A, Product P and year Y+1 to the final universe that you want